# JS: How to test for async function support

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I was wondering if it was even possible to test for async function support in JS.

```
try {
    async () => {}
}
catch (err) {
    // No support
}
```

The above doesn't work as it allows a syntax error to escape in Node v6.

```
/secret/test.js:8
    async () => {}
          ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
```

So what do you think is the best (if any exists) method to test for async support?

Answer (score 3):

use the evil eval

```
var asyncAwait = function() {
        try {
            eval("(function() { async _ => _; })();");
        } catch (e) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }();
```

Note, this fails if the engine supports async/await but does not support arrow notation, however, I believe no such engine exists

Comment: Why the IIFE? Just `eval("(async function() {})")`.

Comment: yeah, I cut/pasted code from an old "es6Features" object I used some time back - tests for all es6+ goodies

Comment: Or probably it's much better to use the `Function` constructor for feature testing like this

Comment: as I said, it's something I wrote a while back, which never saw the light of "production" - think of this code as a guide rather than a definitive answer (that works)